# tcp connection termination 4-way, but I can't see it

Tags: networking, tcp

I got the first three records when I run command 'telnet 192.168.10.109 802' in my mac, then I key 'quit' to the telnet, and I got the next three records. Most people say tcp connection termination need 4-way-handshake, other words the fifth record should be sent in two parts, but this is not the case with my experiments. what is the truth of the case?
[wireshark picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8mqi.png)

Comment: That looks exactly right, but it is not a programming question. _[RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.html)_ explains it, and it has an image of the TCP state machine with explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a answer in *TCP/IP Protocol Suite*, as shown in the picture
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUT3W.png)

Comment: The answer you posted is contained within an image.  That image is not hosted here and could be removed or could suffer link rot in the future.  Please edit your response text to include the answer.